# Select or cut string based on pattern

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have the following input:

`Mission ... some Text ... to Planet 1`

Now, a pattern(regEx) should recognize this string:

`/Mission.*Planet \d{1}/`

So every string that has `Mission` and `Planet {any number}` in it should be valid.

But is it possible to get the Planet with number? In this case, it is a mission to `Planet 1` and is it possible to get the string `Planet 1` out of the input?

Or if the input was `Mission to Planet 3`, I need the string `Planet 3`

You can't simply use the `substr()`-function because there is a unknown number of characters between `Mission` and `Planet {any number}`

Is it necessary to first check, if the string contains is `Mission {any amount of text} Planet {any number}` and then check again just for `Planet {any number}` with `preg_match($regEx, $input, $matches)`

```
$input = "Mission blablabla to Planet 5";
$regex = "/Mission.*Planet \d{1}/";

if(preg_match($regex, $input)) {
    $regexNew = "/Planet \d{1}/";
    preg_match($regexNew, $input, $match));

}
```

So that `$match` contain the planet with its number?

Or is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching and capturing can be done with a single `preg_match()`:

```
Mission.*?(Planet \d)
```

Above expression in English: Match "Mission" followed by any string until "Planet" (lazily) and capture the number that follows. If the number of planets could be greater than 9, use `\d+` instead of `\d`.

```
$input = "Mission blablabla to Planet 5";
$regex = "/Mission.*?(Planet \d)/";

if(preg_match($regex, $input, $match)) {
    echo $match[1]; // => 'Planet 5'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use capture groups:

```
preg_match('/Mission.*(Planet \d+)/', $input, $match);
```

Then use:

```
$match[1];
```

Which will give you `Planet X` (where X is a number).